# Is there any way to prevent a PostgreSQL user to change his/her own password?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, security, users, password

I'm administering a PotsgreSQL server and recently I realized that my "nonsuperuser" users have the possibility to change the secure passwords that I assign them for insecure ones.

I searched in the `REVOKE` docs, but I couldn't find a way to prevent that. It is possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you actually want to prevent them from changing their passwords, or do you want to prevent them from setting a new password unless it's reasonably secure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to prevent a user from changing his/her password. It's been discussed (quite long ago) on ocassion on [PostgreSQL mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/306p9195i31pctqrpugrorjdre0hr7ik1u%404ax.com), and all the answers I remember were basically *"no, you can't"*.

However, there's a contrib module, called [`passwordcheck`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/passwordcheck.html), whose objective is to guarantee the *strength* of passwords, if that's what you wish (as already commented by @RDFozz).

From the docs:

> The `passwordcheck` module checks users' passwords whenever they are set with `CREATE ROLE` or `ALTER ROLE`. If a password is considered too weak, it will be rejected and the command will terminate with an error.
>
> To enable this module, add `'$libdir/passwordcheck'` to `shared_preload_libraries` in `postgresql.conf`, then restart the server.

I've never used the module myself.

Comment: Cool answer didn't know about `passwordcheck`.

Comment: You could use the same hook that `passwordcheck` uses to reject password changes though, I expect. You'd have to write a C extension.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I assume you could just modify `passwordcheck` or configure it in such a way that it refuses *any* password change (let's say, conceptually, that you require all new passwords to be 1.000 chars in length, made of different ASCII characters). However, this would "freeze" whichever roles were already defined, and allow no changes or additions at all... Probably a dangerous scenario.

Comment: @joanolo: noting passwordcheck's reservations about its own security (it primarily validates passwords sent unencrypted on the network, which is a separate risk unless the network itself is encrypted), and also that rewriting passwordcheck could be a major task - hypothetically, if passwordcheck enforces that say the first 4 characters of the password represent a cryptographic checksum of the rest of the password, then ericgcc could generate and set a password but a user would not be able to set a password that would satisfy the test.  But the passwords would be even longer than necessary.

Comment: Afterthought: to prevent password re-use (which I overlooked), you could issue checksigned passwords, then change the salt of the checksign formula so that setting that password again isn't possible.  This will defeat users who decide it is easier to set every user's password to be the same... until you have to give another one out.  That's if Postgresql or passwordcheck don't prevent re-using passwords anyway (preventing re-using a password that a different user used is dubious though).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, I will try the module to enforce password strength